# Netty game server communicate with game thread

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming, netty

I developed a game server using Netty and so far it's working ok. But the internal structure is not good enough, currently the server just receive commands, process and send result back to all clients.

I need that this server runs a separated thread to every gameroom, at 30 or 60 fps, so it calculates physics and movement of all frames of this room. Currently, clients calculates all moviments and obviously I have a lot of problems. I cannot rely on clients...

Questions are:
1) how can I run my game on a separate thread from Netty thread, at some given moment?

2) how to communicate this thread with Netty to process incoming commands?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a new thread is not really related to netty.

Just start it :

```
new Thread( yourRunnable ).start();
```

Or use an `ExecutorService`:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor( );
executor.submit( yourRunnable );
```

Your `Runnable` is probably something like a class which modifies your model continuously. To communicate with netty... just add a controller class with methods which allows you to manipulate the model (getters, setters, any methods you need), and call it from a netty handler when you receives a command from a client.

Take care about concurrent modifications; you will probably need some synchronisation points.